# How can I track the frequency and volume of memory access in a .NET application during memory profiling?

Tags: .net, profiling, memory-profiling

I'm attempting to reduce the memory footprint of a .NET application. Over time this application's use of memory has grown due to developers creating new, duplicate representations of data in memory for various purposes.

I'm would like to determine how frequently these duplicitous representations of data are accessed so that I can decide whether or not to make them short-lived and create-on-access in order to reduce peak working set size.

So my question is - what is the best way to track not only the size and volume of object allocations, **but also the frequency and volume of *accesses* to objects?** I know that all basic memory profilers handle allocation info - correlating that to memory access is what I'm interested in.

To be clear, I'm not looking for an opinionated debate on whether this tool is better than that tool. Rather I'm looking for an answer which tells me how best to solve the problem of accounting for frequency and volume of memory accesses during memory profiling.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not about memory profiling. AFAIK, none of the existing memory profilers track access to data. I would say there are two options here:

- Create some "wrapper" for your data classes that counts access events
- Profile your app using a **performance** profiler, say dotTrace, using the [Tracing](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/help/Profiling_Guidelines__Choosing_the_Right_Profiling_Mode.html) mode. The latter is important as only in the tracing mode you get the exact number of how many times a function was called. In the snapshot, take a look at the number of calls against **getters and setters** of your data classes. Counting the "volume of accesses" can be organized in absolutely the same way depending on the nature of your data. E.g., if you work with some collection, you can count the number of calls to enumerator's get_Current or MoveNext method or smth. similar.